# NSUserDafaults null value?

Tags: ios, null

I have this code

```
[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Identificator"]isEqualToString:@""]
[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Identificator"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

How can I verify is it some value for this key, or not. Because this code return NO

Comment: What you get when you log [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Identificator"] ?

Comment: first accept some answers before asking new things

Comment: give code how you added value

Comment: if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Identificator"]) will check if there is value or not for the key.

Comment: Armaan Stranger, u r right

Answer (score 3):

This will help you though.....

```
 NSUserDefaults *Values = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([[[Values dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"YourKeyToCheck"])
    {
        //return yes ...... Or Do your stuff here...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you,

```
if ([[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Identificator"] length] > 0] {
   //empty value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can have a `NULL` value for a NSUserDefaults key. Setting the value of a key to `nil` is equivalent to removing the key. [check the accepted answer from this SO question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033174/nsuserdefaults-removeobjectforkey-vs-setobjectnil)

As such, your code correctly returns `NO` because that key does not exist.

So you should adapt your code accordingly and do whatever you need to do on the `NO` result, not `YES` I would say.