# Synchronizing NSUserDefaults has no effect

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

In my iPhone-application I am deleting keys using either `removeObjectForKey:@"bla"` or `setObject:nil forKey:@"bla"` in `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`.

**However**, when I do it just before I push a new view controller onto the navigation controller stack, the defaults do not get updated.

If I do it in `viewDidAppear` in the pushed controller that is then displayed, the `synchronize` call does what is expected.

I don't understand this behavior. Did anyone ever have a similar problem?

**Summary:** delete+synchronize just before pushing new VC: NSUserDefaults stay the same. delete+synchronize in `viewDidAppear` and it works.

I also tried using `setPersistentDomain:forName:`, but the result was the same..

Edit: Here's the code:

```
+ (void)deleteDefaultEntries
{
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

  [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"key1"];
  [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"key2"];
  [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"key3"];
  [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"key4"];

  [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: You are really trying to save just a fixed string or maybe some variables connected to ViewController ?

Comment: I'm trying to delete keys that are in NSUserDefaults. Just strings. 4 to be exact.

Comment: Did you try to put NSLogs or breakpoints to make sure code is executed as you expect ? especially synchronize ? Also maybe you are clearing them before pushing viewcontroller and overwriting it anyways in next viewController ? You are using it correctly, so it must be something else.

Comment: @Grzegorz: Yeah I stepped through and synchronise gets called. I think it might be some sort of bug in iOS.. Even if I output the defaults immediately afterwards, the deletion is undone. IF I call it just before pushing, that is. .. anyway, I have my workaround. I was just wondering if that's a unique problem with my app or sth else...

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right, I'm sure it's not iOS bug, but try this:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"example key"]`

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033174/nsuserdefaults-removeobjectforkey-vs-setobjectnil).